# WilliamChart not possible to use Animations properly - Easing and methods missing

Tags: android, animation, gradle, charts, linechart

I tried everything to get a simple Animation done in WilliamChart.
But the only thing I can change is the duration of the Animation.

I used the Application on the App Store "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.db.williamchartdemo&hl=de" to extract the customized Code and implement it to my Chart.

Everything is working, but the Animation is not possible to implement (see Screenshots). **Easing and all animation methods are not available.**
Maybe I've done something wrong in Gradle. But I can't help myself no more.
[Animation Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwd09.png)

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/JJoGM  - Error in import
http://imgur.com/a/KaVSY - Gradle imports

Comment: probably it uses custom Animation class. check imports

Comment: Where can I check the imports? Because on his page "https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/wiki/(7)-Animation" he isn't mentioning a external class

Comment: It seems these methods belong to older versions and now removed. See the link for setEasing method replaced with setInterpolater https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/commit/d242dbcdd4adcbae8119bbf9aacdd352a09cb706

Comment: So you should follow the uptodate tutorial to implement animation properly

Comment: @uguboz maaaaaaaaan how did you find this. Really you're the king.
Love you. All probs to you bro :D